# jQuery append trouble with url parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators, append

I've been working for hours trying to get the single and double quotes nested correctly in order for this search result display to work, with having a dynamically appended "uniqueId" in part of the URL string on output.

Basically, the part of the JS code that is giving me trouble is this:

```
$('#results-list').append("<li rel='" + this.uniqueId + "'>" + this.dateTimeStamp + "&nbsp;&#8212;&nbsp;" + this.message + "&nbsp;&#8212;&nbsp;" + "<a class='iframeSmaller' href='commentDetails.php?uniqueId='" + this.uniqueId + "''>XXX</a>" + "</li>");
```

I want to have the "this.uniqueId" after the equal sign so that it generates a dynamic URL, which I then am going to link to a "details" page for that unique ID.

Can anyone please help me with the "this.uniqueId" syntax to get this correctly inserted into the URL for output?

Sorry if I am being unclear, I am learning all of this by the day :)

thanks!

ps... this does work, but it has a hardcoded uniqueID... what I want is a dynamic one based on the row, which is working as far as the "rel" part goes, just not the anchor part...

```
$('#results-list').append("<li rel='" + this.uniqueId + "'>" + this.dateTimeStamp + "&nbsp;&#8212;&nbsp;" + this.message + "&nbsp;&#8212;&nbsp;" + "<a class='iframeSmaller' href='commentDetails.php?uniqueId=32'>XXX</a>" + "</li>");
```

thanks again for any help with this syntax (or if there's a better way to go about what I'm trying to do)...

Comment: and just to be clear, the "this.uniqueId" works fine in the "rel" part of the list item, it's just the insertion of the "this.uniqueId" in the anchor part of this code that is giving me trouble...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quoting in your HTML for the anchor isn't quite right.  You have this:

```
+ "<a class='iframeSmaller' href='commentDetails.php?uniqueId='" + this.uniqueId + "''>XXX</a>" +
```

I think it should be this (fix quoting on the link URL):

```
+ "<a class='iframeSmaller' href='commentDetails.php?uniqueId=" + this.uniqueId + "'>XXX</a>" +
```

You could see what's going on better if you build the string into a variable and then do a `console.log()` on the string of HTML you've built or look at its contents in the debugger.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!! this totally worked... I guess I was so close, but yet so far... thank you so, so much for your prompt reply, I was going crazy moving single and double quotes around trying to get it to work!!! :)

Comment: Along with the quoting issues, `uniqueId` might not be correctly encoded for use in a url. You should run `uniqueId` through `encodeURIComponent` first to be sure it is correctly encoded for the resulting URL. [More Details](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part of your code:

```
... uniqueId='" + this.uniqueId + "''>XXX</a>" + "</li>");
```

for this one:

```
... uniqueId=" + this.uniqueId + "'>XXX</a>" + "</li>");
```

Comment: thank you as well for your reply, it's great there's this site of experts to help!